# How to use Application.Exit() only once

Tags: c#, winforms

When I tried applying an auto connect to a default user in C# windows forms, I ran into a problem. In the first login, the username and password were entered automatically from the database (1, 1). Then I save a boolean like this in the app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="FirstRun" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

And on the login form, I use the auto login like that:

```
    private void login_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(config.AppSettings.Settings["FirstRun"].Value))
            Application.Exit();
    }

    private void login_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(config.AppSettings.Settings["FirstRun"].Value))
        {

            bool bAutoLogin = DB.GetAutoLoginSetting(cnn);
            if (bAutoLogin)
            {
                user.Text = "1";
                pass.Text = "1";
                GoToNext(); //Preforms the actual log in.
            }
            else
            {
                this.ActiveControl = user;
                user.Select(0, user.Text.Length);
            }
            config.AppSettings.Settings["FirstRun"].Value = false.ToString(); ;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        }
    }
```

After the first login has already been completed, the application opens another instance of the program from the moment it is running. The application exits completely if I remove the condition in login_FormClosing.

Comment: You should do this in `main`. Run the main Form only if the condition is auto or if the dialog result of showing (.ShowDialog();) the login Form returns `DialogResult.OK` which indicates a successful account validation. Otherwise, call `Application.ExitThread();`.